# Проблема с настройкой nginx

Tags: nginx

После установки системы на новый компьютер заново настраивал nginx, скопировал и отредактировал предыдущий конфиг, пробовал и новый писать. Элементарная вещь по каким-то причинам не работает, а именно - определение по блокам `server`.У меня есть блоки с `server_name`:
1) chat.lw.lh
2) lw.lh www.lw.lh
В первом блоке простой `proxy_pass`, но он не работает. Как оказалось, проблема не в этом - этот блок просто не выбирается даже при адресе chat.lw.lh, собственно, как и второй (!) - я проверил это тем, что www.lw.lh не работает. Работает только просто lw.lh, а блок второй как-то по дефолту выбирается. Заставить работать ну никак не могу, буду благодарен за любую помощь.

[Весь конфиг](http://pastebin.com/hXxp7Gpf)

Comment: А может, вовсе и не в nginx тут дело? Конфиг-то правильный! Может просто на неймсервере эти имена не прописаны, например?

Comment: @areshin, ОМФГ, `etc/hosts`, ну как, как я мог случайно забыть про него? ...Спасибо. Даже и сказать то нечего)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень похоже, что вы пытаетесь применить старые конфиги к новому nginx! А если сами правили,то тоже в прежнем стиле! А между тем, там много чего изменилось! Какую вресию nginx вы юзаете? Если вендовую,то она дырявая!

Comment: Я и новые пробовал писать. Во всяком случае, я приложил полностью конфиг тот, с которым пытаюсь (и не вижу причины неудачи).  Версия 1.2.1, ubuntu.

Comment: Начнём с того, что nginx сам по себе редко где использунтся, а обычяно стоит прокладкой лля Апача. Может, в этом дело?

Comment: В смысле? Я показывают, что он не исполняет самое элеметарное - выбор нужного блока директив `server` по имени хоста. И почему такая фигня - понять не могу, может не вижу в упор чего-то?

Comment: Поясните попонятнеее, пожалуйста! Желательно, с логами.

Comment: Там не  получается отсечка по именни хоста, или что?

Comment: @areshin, логи уже ставил аж на уровень `debug`, там вроде как ничего интересного не увидел.  Да, я и говорю - он всегда выбирает второй блок (который lw.lh www.lw.lh) для lw.lh, и всё, больше ничё не работает, ни www туда же, ни chat в первый блок.  Но ведь конфиг то правильно написан, где там можно ошибиться?

Comment: Да я и сам там ошибок явных не вижу! Непонятно... А у вас это в сети происходит, или при обращении через локалхост тоже?

Comment: У меня это на компе стоит моём же для себя самого.